# MS Word hyperlink font format bug?

Tags: hyperlink, fonts, ms-word

I have problem with hyperlink `font` format in `word 2003/2007` maybe it is in other too but i didn't try it.

First i create `hyperlink` in my `document`, then i change format of hyperlinks in 
*Styles and Formatting*
for example: **Bold, Italic size: 10, font: `Webdings`.** Everything is ok, format is changed.

Problem happens when i add next `hyperlink` through ctrl + k (or insert hyperlink it doesnt matter). It accepts the most of format. It is **Bold, Italic,** even change color works, but font always stays as `Times New Roman` 12.

when i change format of `hyperlink` after this, the first hyperlink is ok. Changed `color`, styles an `font`. The others that were added later changes their color, style but not font. It is still Times new Roman 12.

When i select them they are style of hyperlink. When i set them as style hyperlink again (e.g. with enter), then they change its font to webdings too, but i need to accept this font without this, because i want to generate document with visual basic from template, and hyperlinks that are already in template accept new font in template but hyperlinks added with VB doesnt accept new font. And always select added hyperlink and set its type to hyperlink again ... it seams a bit wierd to me...

Does anybody know solution for this problem? i am trying to google it for two days and without success...

**Edit:** I found out right now, that it doesn't set format `Times new roman 12`, but it set the same format as it is set in *Normal* font. But format is shown to be set to *hyperlink* not to *Normal*. but again when i changed normal format it doesnt accept change to allready created hyperlinks, but only accept it to new one... i dont know but i have feel that it works really wierd and all this rules doesnt apply everytime...

Comment: What VBA code are you using to add hyperlinks to the document?

Comment: `doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, Address:= sLine5, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=sLine4)`, where sline variables are read from inputit. works exactly like when i add link in word and the problems are same too.